# как добавить AJAXом sql запрос

Tags: javascript, php, sql, phpmyadmin

не получается сделать запрос на добавление записи с помощью AJAX.
JS срабатывает, вроде нормально, насколько я понимаю у меня где-то ошибка в PHP.

PHP:

```
include 'ajax.php';

    $value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'todo-description');
    $date = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'date');

    if (isset($_POST['todo-description'])) {
        echo 'PHP SRABOTAL' . $_POST['todo-description'];
        function putTodoInBase($db) {
                    $k = rand(1, 1000);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `Todo` (`id`, `todo-name`, `todo-description`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, `test`, :value, :date)";      
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':value' => $value, ':date' => $date));
        }

    }
```

JS:

```
 let params = 'todo-description=' + textAreaValue + '&' + 'date=' + dateNow;
    SendRequest('POST', 'api.php', params,requestAlert);


function SendRequest(r_method, r_path, r_args, r_handler)
{
    //Создаём запрос
    let Request = CreateRequest();
    //Проверяем существование запроса еще раз
    if (!Request)
    {
        return;
    }
    //Назначаем пользовательский обработчик
    Request.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        //Если обмен данными завершен
        if (Request.readyState == 4)
        {
            //Передаем управление обработчику пользователя
            r_handler(Request);
        }
    }
    //Проверяем, если требуется сделать GET-запрос
    if (r_method.toLowerCase() == "get" && r_args.length > 0)
        r_path += "?" + r_args;
    //Инициализируем соединение
    Request.open(r_method, r_path, true);
    if (r_method.toLowerCase() == "post")
    {
        //Если это POST-запрос 
        //Устанавливаем заголовок
        Request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
        //Посылаем запрос
        Request.send(r_args);
        alert('AJAX POSLAN');
    } else
    {
        //Если это GET-запрос
        //Посылаем нуль-запрос
        Request.send(null);
    }
}

function CreateRequest()
{
    let Request = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        //Gecko-совместимые браузеры, Safari, Konqueror
        Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        //Internet explorer
        try
        {
            Request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (CatchException)
        {
            Request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    if (!Request)
    {
        alert("Невозможно создать XMLHttpRequest");
    }
    return Request;
}
```

БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: функция `putTodoInBase` где-нибудь вызывается? *"я понимаю у меня где-то ошибка в PHP."* - включите отладчик и пройдитесь построчно, посмотрите.

Comment: Она  разве не должна срабатывать сама, если  `echo 'PHP SRABOTAL' . $_POST['todo-description'];` срабатывает?

Comment: Вы когда функции пишите они у вас автоматически срабатывают или всё же вы пишите их вызов?

Comment: Кстати  `VALUES (NULL, 'test', ':value', ':date')` <--- вот тут не нужно :value и :date брать в апострофы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почемуто в 
$value;
$date был  null, пока сделал так... + я не вызывал функцию

```
     function putTodoInBase($db) {
        $k = rand(1, 1000);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `Todo` (`id`, `todo-name`, `todo-description`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '$k', :value, :date)";      
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(':value' => $_POST['todo-description'], ':date' => $_POST['date']));
    }

putTodoInBase($db);
```